# getch(); does not pause the loop

Tags: c, getch

I have this piece of code for instance:

```
while(true){
    printf("looping");
    getch();
}
```

Instead of waiting for user input on each loop, the loop just continues without me; printing

```
loop
loop
loop
```

until I close the program.

Is there a better way to read a single character ? All i really want to do is to have the user input a 'y' or a 'n'

Comment: `getch` is a non-standard extension. There are two incompatible versions in common use. One is provided for MS Windows, one is provided in curses. What operating environment are you using?

Comment: `All i really want to do is to have the user input a 'y' or a 'n'` means what you don't want other character as input? also make clear what you want to do if input is 'y' or 'n'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use fgetc. I assume you're using this to break out of the loop, so to update your example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char iput;

while(true){
    printf("looping");
    iput = fgetc(stdin);
    if(iput == 'n')
      break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
   while(1)
 {
   printf("\nlooping");
   char t=getch();
   if(t=='n')
   exit(0);
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use

```
fflush(stdin)
```

before calling getch

regards